# Where clause Google Cloud Firestore in StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add a where clause on a cloud Firestore query in a streambuilder. My problem is that my list appear then disappear ...
Here is my code.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('nomquetuveux')
          .orderBy('valid').where('valid', isEqualTo: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Chargement ...');
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(children: <Widget>[
                _buildListItem(
                    context,
                    snapshot.data.documents[index]['libelle'],
                    snapshot.data.documents[index]['valid']),
                Divider(),
              ]);
            });
      }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can try debug it by doing the following.

```
QuerySnapshot documents = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('nomquetuveux')
      .orderBy('valid').where('valid', isEqualTo: true)
      .getDocuments().catchError(
           (error) {print(error);}
      );
```

In this way you can see if the error is thrown by the query execution